# Construct a Pandas dataframe from list of nested dictionaries containing some missing keys/values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using an API to retrieve a list of nested dictionaries containing data from an online survey.  The data looks as follows:

```
filtered_messages = [{'type': 'message',
  'subtype': 'bot_message',
  'text': "This content can't be displayed.",
  'ts': '1654800705.715459',
  'username': 'Typeform',
  'icons': {'image_48': 'www.example.com'},
  'bot_id': 'ABC4K1SJE',
  'app_id': 'DEFSC3RT6',
  'blocks': [{'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'GUoS',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': 'You have a new message.',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'abZ',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Where did you first hear about us?*\nAdvertisement',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'lEd',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Reason for purchase: *\nLeisure',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': '4=vEY',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Where do you reside? *\nNew York',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'P1SKA',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Are you purchasing online or in store? *\nIn Store',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'f74v',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*What was the location of your purchase? *\nNew York / City',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': '3tr6',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Would you be open to being interviewed by our team? *\nYes',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'aGz',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Any other feedback/questions for us? *\nYou guys are amazing',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': '3A4Y',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Order Number:*\n138405',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'actions',
    'block_id': 'KNSXk',
    'elements': [{'type': 'button',
      'action_id': '4nR',
      'text': {'type': 'plain_text', 'text': 'View results', 'emoji': True},
      'url': 'www.example.com'}]},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'kSjX4',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn', 'text': ' ', 'verbatim': False}}]},
 {'type': 'message',
  'subtype': 'bot_message',
  'text': "This content can't be displayed.",
  'ts': '1654457958.167459',
  'username': 'Typeform',
  'icons': {'image_48': 'www.example.com'},
  'bot_id': 'BPD4K3SJW',
  'app_id': 'AD6SC3RT6',
  'blocks': [{'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'Y8w',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': 'You have a new message.',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': '9DGN',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Where did you first hear about us?*\nFriend',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': '=JF',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Reason for purchase: *\nBusiness',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': '3FY/t',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Where do you reside? *\nScotland',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': '8yz',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Are you purchasing online or in store? *\nOnline',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'PSm',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*What was the location of your purchase? *\nLondon',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'fytG',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Would you be open to being interviewed by our team? *\nNo',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'S8LaL',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Order Number:*\n140829',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'actions',
    'block_id': 'ZON',
    'elements': [{'type': 'button',
      'action_id': '02eV',
      'text': {'type': 'plain_text', 'text': 'View results', 'emoji': True},
      'url': 'www.example.com'}]},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'zeVIW',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn', 'text': ' ', 'verbatim': False}}]}]
```

I would like to create a Pandas dataframe that looks as follows:

```
ts                   heard_about_us   reason_for_purchase   customer_location   purchase_modality       purchase_location    agree_to_interview   comments                order_number
1654800705.715459    Advertisement    Leisure               New York            In Store                New York / City      Yes                  You guys are amazing    138405
1654457958.167459    Friend           Business              Scotland            Online                  London               No                                           140829
```

The column names align with the questions inside the `text` element (enclosed in asterisks '*').

To do so, I'm using the following code:

```
survey_data = pd.DataFrame(data=[[re.sub(".*[*]\\W+", "", val['text']['text']) for val in dat['blocks'] if val.get('text')][1:9] for dat in filtered_messages],
                 columns=['heard_about_us', 'reason_for_purchase', 'customer_location', 'purchase_modality', 'purchase_location', 'agree_to_interview', 'comments', 'order_number']
                  )
```

The result is the following:

```
ts                   heard_about_us   reason_for_purchase   customer_location   purchase_modality       purchase_location    agree_to_interview   comments                order_number
1654800705.715459    Advertisement    Leisure               New York            In Store                New York / City      Yes                  You guys are amazing    138405
1654457958.167459    Friend           Business              Scotland            Online                  London               No                   140829
```

Notice that the order ID `140829` is shifted to the left because there is no `comments` field in that survey record (because some of the survey questions are not mandatory).

To overcome this, I have tried to use `pd.json.normalize()` to create the `df`:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(filtered_messages,
                        record_path = ['blocks'],
                        meta = ['type', 'text'],
                        errors = 'ignore',
                        record_prefix = '_'
                       )
```

But, this results in a `df` with a `_text.text` ***column*** containing ***rows*** representing each of the elements that I'd like to see expressed as columns.  Here is a small sample of the output:

```
     type      _block_id    _text.type  _text.text                                          _text.verbatim    _elements    type     text
0    section   GUoS         mrkdwn      You have a new message.                             False             NaN          message  This content can't be displayed.
1    section   abZ          mrkdwn      *Where did you first hear about us?*\nAdvertis...   False             NaN          message  This content can't be displayed.
2    section   lEd          mrkdwn      *Reason for purchase: *\nLeisure                    False             NaN          message  This content can't be displayed.
3    section   4=vEY        mrkdwn      *Where do you reside? *\nNew York                   False             NaN          message  This content can't be displayed.
4    section   P1SKA        mrkdwn      *Are you purchasing online or in store? *\nIn ...   False             NaN          message  This content can't be displayed.
5    section   f74v         mrkdwn      *What was the location of your purchase? *\nNe...   False             NaN          message  This content can't be displayed.
6    section   3tr6         mrkdwn      *Would you be open to being interviewed by our...   False             NaN          message  This content can't be displayed.
7    section   aGz          mrkdwn      *Any other feedback/questions for us? *\nYou g...   False             NaN          message  This content can't be displayed.
8    section   3A4Y         mrkdwn      *Order Number:*\n138405                             False             NaN          message  This content can't be displayed.
9    actions   KNSXk        NaN         NaN                                                 NaN               [{'type': 'button', 'action_id': '4nR', 'text'... message This content can't be displayed
```

How would I access the required elements inside of `blocks` to create the `df`?  Potentially using the questions enclosed inside the asterisks (*) as the keys of a dictionary?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you check "'*Where do you reside? *\Scotland'". Missing `\n`?

Comment: @Corralien -- yes, it should have been *\nScotland.  Thanks for catching that.  I've edited the post.

Comment: I updated my answer with the right output. Can you check it please?

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
# Mapping
mapping = {
    'Where did you first hear about us?': 'heard_about_us',
    'Reason for purchase:': 'reason_for_purchase',
    'Where do you reside?': 'customer_location',
    'Are you purchasing online or in store?': 'purchase_modality',
    'What was the location of your purchase?': 'purchase_location',
    'Would you be open to being interviewed by our team?': 'agree_to_interview',
    'Any other feedback/questions for us?': 'comments',
    'Order Number:': 'order_number'
}

# Use your options here but don't forget 'ts' meta
df = pd.json_normalize(filtered_messages, record_path=['blocks'], 
                       meta=['ts', 'type', 'text'], record_prefix='_')

# Extract question/answer
df1 = df['_text.text'].str.extract(r'\*(?P<question>[^\*]+)\*\s+(?P<answer>.*)')

# Create final dataframe
out = pd.concat([df['ts'], df1], axis=1).dropna()
out['question'] = out['question'].str.strip().replace(mapping)

# Reshape it
out = (out.pivot('ts', 'question', 'answer')[mapping.values()]
          .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
                  ts heard_about_us reason_for_purchase customer_location purchase_modality purchase_location agree_to_interview              comments order_number
0  1654457958.167459         Friend            Business          Scotland            Online            London                 No                   NaN       140829
1  1654800705.715459  Advertisement             Leisure          New York          In Store   New York / City                Yes  You guys are amazing       138405
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.json_normalize(filtered_messages, ['blocks'], 'ts')[['ts', 'text.text']]
df.columns = ['ts', 'text']
df.text.replace(' ', np.nan, inplace=True)
df.text.replace('You have a new message.', np.nan, inplace=True)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df[['question', 'answer']] = df.apply(lambda x: x.text.strip('*').split('*'), axis=1, result_type='expand')
df = df.pivot(index='ts', columns='question', values='answer')
df.columns = ['comments', 'purchase_modality', 'order_number', 'reason_for_purchase', 'purchase_location', 'heard_about_us', 'customer_location', 'agree_to_interview']
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip().strip('\\'), na_action='ignore')
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
                  ts              comments purchase_modality order_number reason_for_purchase purchase_location heard_about_us customer_location agree_to_interview
0  1654457958.167459                   NaN            Online       140829            Business            London         Friend          Scotland                 No
1  1654800705.715459  You guys are amazing          In Store       138405             Leisure   New York / City  Advertisement          New York                Yes
```